# execute sleep() onTouchEvent or Control frame rate in surfaceview (android )

Tags: android, multithreading, surfaceview

Please check this [link](http://www.rbgrn.net/content/342-using-input-pipelines-your-android-game). Following code is from this link. I am not sure why it says we have to use thread sleep to limit number of touch events. 
I have a surfaceview and gamethread which processes events pushed by touch event. Is this sleep required or should I handle the sleep in gamethread instead by controlling framerate.

```
 try {
    Thread.sleep(16);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    }
    return true;
    }
```

whole code

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
// we only care about down actions in this game.
try {
// history first
int hist = event.getHistorySize();
if (hist > 0) {
// add from oldest to newest
for (int i = 0; i < hist; i++) {
InputObject input = inputObjectPool.take();
input.useEventHistory(event, i);
gameThread.feedInput(input);
}
}
// current last
InputObject input = inputObjectPool.take();
input.useEvent(event);
gameThread.feedInput(input);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
}
// don't allow more than 60 motion events per second
try {
Thread.sleep(16);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
}
return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your link points to an article that has been posted in 2009, you should really try to find one that is more up to date.

The code itself looks wrong, the author explains that his code is designed to avoid blocking the UI thread but then calls Thread.sleep(16) in `onTouchEvent()` which is called from the UI thread and blocks it.

What about this example? I haven't read it in detail, but the code looks much better : https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/827608/Android-Basic-Game-Loop